# Can I get the equation of a sine function, based on its maximum/minimum points, and a set of points in its phase?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

So I Have a set of points in a phase of a sine function, and I need a its function.
The Points are:
(0; 1), (1; 3), (2; 2), (3; -1), (4; -3), (5; -2)
Maximum is the point (1; 3), Minimum is the point(4; -3).
Of course, this is a sine function, so the next points I need go respectively:
(6; 1), (7; 3), (8; 2), (9; -1), (10; -3), (11; -2).
Is it actually possible to find a function like this? And the second set of points isn't actually THAT important, because of my needs.

Answer (score 0):

ASin(Bx+c)

A=amplitude (how high it goes from the middle line to the highest or lowest point. In sin(x), it rises from the origin to one, then goes down to -1, so it's amplitude is 1).

B= period (how long it takes to repeat. Just divide 2pi/b to get the new period.)

c=phase shift. It's where you start from the origin. Negative c shifts right, positive c shifts left.

Comment: Well, I do know that, but I can't get the equation based on that, because no equation Asin(bx + c) + d satisfies my set of points.